# Chaincode explanation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am a new to hyper ledger fabric. I understand the general idea of how hyper ledger works. However, The chaincode still confuses me.

1. What is the `shim` package?
2. What are the `init` and `invoke` methods are for?
3. Also, the syntax of the chaincode. For example, I read code like this in the init method:

   ```
    func (t *SampleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response.
   ```

Any explanation of these questions would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you read Chapter 4 "Designing a Data and Transaction Model with Golang" in "Hands-On Blockchain with Hyperledger: Building decentralized applications with Hyperledger Fabric and Composer" book, it has a good explanation on all of your questions.

[https://www.amazon.com/Hands-Blockchain-Hyperledger-decentralized-applications/dp/1788994523](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788994523)

Comment: Oh snap...... I didnt see that coming. That was a nice explanation/solution. You couldnt give the solution instead of trying to sell a book.